# How to get the current Title of a Window parented to my Form?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, process, ui-automation

I've got a WinForm app that parents Windows of other processes (ex. Google Chrome). I'm using the following code to parent a Windows to my Form, using the Handle returned by `[Process].MainWindowHandle`.
I'm trying to find the `MainWindowTitle` of all the Windows that are parented to my Form, so I can display their name on a Label.

When the Window of a WebBrowser is *embedded*, the Title will change when a different Web Page is selected, switching Tabs.

The code I have for starting the program does work as it should:

```
ProcessStartInfo ps1 = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:/Users/Jacob/AppData/Roaming/Spotify/Spotify.exe");
ps1.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
Process p1 = Process.Start(ps1);
// Allow the process to open it's window
Thread.Sleep(1000);
appWin1 = p1.MainWindowHandle;
spotify = p1;

// Put it into this form
SetParent(appWin1, this.Handle);
// Move the window to overlay it on this window
MoveWindow(appWin1, 0, 70, this.Width / 2, this.Height/2, true);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're willing to use [UIAutomation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation) to handle this *parenting* affair, I propose to handle this using Automation methods entirely. Almost, `SetParent` still required :).

The class shown here uses the [WindowPatter.WindowOpenedEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.windowpattern.windowopenedevent) to detect and notify when a new Window is opened in the System.
It can be any Window, Console included (still a Window).
This method allows to identify a Window when it's handle is already created, so you don't need an arbitrary *time-out* or try to use `Process.WaitForInputIdle()`, which may not have the desired result.

You can pass a list of names of processes to the `ProcessNames` Property of the class: when any Window that belongs to one of these Processes is opened,   UIAutomation detects it and a public event is raised. It notifies the subscribers that one of the Processes in the list has opened a Window, which is the `ProcessId` of the Owner and the handle of the Windows.
These values are passed in a custom `EventArgs` class, `ProcessStartedArgs` when the `ProcessStarted` event is raised.

Since the Automation Event is raised in a Thread other than the UI Thread, the class captures the [SynchronizationContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.synchronizationcontext) where the class is created (the UI Thread, since you're probably creating this class in a Form) and marshals the event to that Thread, calling its [Post()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.post) method passing a [SendOrPostCallback](http://SendOrPostCallback) delegate.
This way, you can safely pass the Handle of your Form and the Handle of the Window to `SetParent()`.

To retrieve the current Title (Caption) of the parented Window, pass the Handle previously returned in the event argument to the `GetCurrentWindowTitle()` method. If the Window contains tabbed child Windows, as a Web Browser, this method will return the Title related to the Tab currently selected.

▶ The class is disposable and you need to call its public `Dispose()` method. This removes the Automation event handler and also all the events in the Invocation List of the public event you have subscribed to. This way, you can use a Lambda to subscribe to the event.

---

Use a Field to store an instance of this class. Create the instance when needed, passing a List of Process Names you're interested in.
Subscribe to the `ProcessStarted` event.
When on of these Processes opens a new Window, you'll get a notification and the parenting thing can be performed:

```
public partial class SomeForm : Form
{
    private WindowWatcher watcher = null;

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        watcher = new WindowWatcher();
        watcher.ProcessNames.AddRange(new[] { "msedge", "firefox", "chrome", "notepad" });

        watcher.ProcessStarted += (o, ev) => {
            SetParent(ev.WindowHandle, this.Handle);
            MoveWindow(ev.WindowHandle, 0, 70, this.Width / 2, this.Height / 2, true);
            string windowTitle = WindowWatcher.GetCurrentWindowTitle(ev.WindowHandle);
        };
    }

    protected override void OnFormClosed(FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        watcher.Dispose();
        base.OnFormClosed(e);
    }
}
```

**`WindowWatcher` class:**

**NOTE**: [UI Automation assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation) are part of `Windows Presentation Framework`.
When one of these assemblies is referenced in a WinForms application, the WinForms application will become DpiAware (`SystemAware`), if it's not already DpiAware.
This can have an impact on the Layout of one or more Forms that is not designed to handle Dpi Awareness changes and notifications.

Requires a Project Reference to:

- UIAutomationClient
- UIAutomationTypes

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Automation;

public class WindowWatcher : IDisposable
{
    private SynchronizationContext context = null;
    private readonly SendOrPostCallback eventCallback;
    public event EventHandler<ProcessStartedArgs> ProcessStarted;
    private AutomationElement uiaWindow;
    private AutomationEventHandler WindowOpenedHandler;

    public WindowWatcher() {
        context = SynchronizationContext.Current;
        eventCallback = new SendOrPostCallback(EventHandlersInvoker);
        InitializeWatcher();
    }

    public List<string> ProcessNames { get; set; } = new List<string>();

    private void InitializeWatcher()
    {
        Automation.AddAutomationEventHandler(
            WindowPattern.WindowOpenedEvent, AutomationElement.RootElement,
            TreeScope.Children, WindowOpenedHandler = new AutomationEventHandler(OnWindowOpenedEvent));
    }

    public static string GetCurrentWindowTitle(IntPtr handle)
    {
        if (handle == IntPtr.Zero) return string.Empty;
        var element = AutomationElement.FromHandle(handle);
        if (element != null) {
            return element.Current.Name;
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }

    private void OnWindowOpenedEvent(object uiaElement, AutomationEventArgs e)
    {
        uiaWindow = uiaElement as AutomationElement;
        if (uiaWindow == null || uiaWindow.Current.ProcessId == Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id) return;
        var window = uiaWindow.Current;

        var procName = string.Empty;
        using (var proc = Process.GetProcessById(window.ProcessId)) {
            if (proc == null) throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid Process");
            procName = proc.ProcessName;
        }

        if (ProcessNames.IndexOf(procName) >= 0) {
            var args = new ProcessStartedArgs(procName, window.ProcessId, (IntPtr)window.NativeWindowHandle);
            context.Post(eventCallback, args);
        }
    }

    public class ProcessStartedArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public ProcessStartedArgs(string procName, int procId, IntPtr windowHandle)
        {
            ProcessName = procName;
            ProcessId = procId;
            WindowHandle = windowHandle;
        }

        public string ProcessName { get; }
        public int ProcessId { get; }
        public IntPtr WindowHandle { get; }
    }

    private void EventHandlersInvoker(object state)
    {
        if (!(state is ProcessStartedArgs args)) return;
        ProcessStarted?.Invoke(this, args);
    }

    ~WindowWatcher() { Dispose(false); }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (uiaWindow != null && WindowOpenedHandler != null) {
            Automation.RemoveAutomationEventHandler(
                WindowPattern.WindowOpenedEvent, uiaWindow, WindowOpenedHandler);
        }
            
        if (ProcessStarted != null) {
            var invList = ProcessStarted.GetInvocationList();
            if (invList != null && invList.Length > 0) {
                for (int i = invList.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    ProcessStarted -= (EventHandler<ProcessStartedArgs>)invList[i];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```