# How to get the handle of a process that invokes an APP URI

Tags: c#, wpf, handle

So I want to get the window handle of the ZOOM Window after I start/join the meeting. I can open ZOOM via the process command. I'm stuck currently on getting the handle for it.

When I try to do `p.MainWindowHandle`, I get an exception that the process is already closed.

```
        Process p = Process.Start("zoommtg://zoom.us/join?action=join&confno=....................");
        p.WaitForInputIdle();
        //p.WaitForInputIdle();
        //GetTopWindow((IntPtr)null);
        SetParent(p.MainWindowHandle, CBox.Handle);
        //SendMessage(p.MainWindowHandle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MAXIMIZE, 0);
```

Other Ideas:

1. I found the function `GetTopWindow()` but I'm not knowing how to parse null to get a system-wide search.

Thank  You for the help

#### Question Again

1. How do you get the window handle of an app that was started by an APP URI
2. How do you use 'GetTopWindow()' in C# to get the top most window in the system

Comment: Try with the WindowWatcher class [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66755883/7444103). It uses UI Automation, so read the notes about DpiAwarenes if you have a non-DpiAware GUI app.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19867402/how-can-i-use-enumwindows-to-find-windows-with-a-specific-caption-title